# How to get this nested data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

I'm trying to get this nested data from firebase database. I have made three classes Company , Vehicle , and Destination. I want to retrieve this data any suggestion. I retrieves only Company info but not its two childs Vehicles and Destinations.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private TextView tvID, tvCompanyName, tvCompanyAddress, tvCompanyContact, tvCompanyStatus, tvCarNumber;
private String startingPoint, endingPoint, fare, car, carModel, carNumber;
private Button btnGo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvID = findViewById(R.id.tvID);
    tvCompanyName = findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);
    tvCompanyAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyAddress);
    tvCompanyContact = findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyContact);
    tvCompanyStatus = findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyStatus);
    tvCarNumber = findViewById(R.id.tvCarNumber);
```

myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://travel-cdae5.firebaseio.com/company/companies");

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                try {
                        Company company = dataSnapshot.getValue(Company.class);
                        Destination destination = dataSnapshot.getValue(Destination.class);
                        tvID.setText(company.getId());
                        tvCompanyName.setText(company.getName());
                        tvCompanyAddress.setText(company.getAddress());
                        tvCompanyContact.setText(company.getContact());
                        tvCompanyStatus.setText(destination.getFare());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    Log.e("Message", exp.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exp.getMessage()
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage()
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Share the structure of your database

Comment: @YashKrishan https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytcun.png

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to get? Please provide us an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destinations is a child of the company node that is why you have to fetch it as a child using `DataSnapshot destinationsSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("destinations").getValue();`

Then you need to iterate over the destinations returned.

Code:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            try {
            Company company = dataSnapshot.getValue(Company.class);
            tvID.setText(company.getId());
            tvCompanyName.setText(company.getName());
            tvCompanyAddress.setText(company.getAddress());
            tvCompanyContact.setText(company.getContact());
            DataSnapshot destinationsSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("destinations").getValue();
                    // Now iterate over the destinations 
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    if (snapshot.getKey().equals(0)){
                        Destination destination = snapshot.getValue(Destination.class);
                        tvCompanyStatus.setText(destination.getFare());
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                Log.e("Message", exp.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exp.getMessage()
                        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage()
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to get only the index [0] data.